# Change div value based on <select> option

Tags: jquery

Using this great plugin

http://exodecreations.com/jQuery/jqDropDown.html

My Jquery code:

```
jQuery(function() {  
  jQuery('#list4').jqDropDown({ 
    optionChanged: function(){
      jQuery("#firmos").html('My New Text');
    }, 
    direction: 'up', 
    defaultStyle: false, 
    containerName: 'theContainer', 
    toggleBtnName: 'awesomeToggleClass', 
    optionListName: 'thisListIsRocking', 
    effect: 'fade', 
    effectSpeed: 300 
  });
});
```

My php code:

```
<form action="#">
  <select id="list4" name="invoices">
    <option>Aspen</option>
    <option>Tokyo</option>
    <option>Cannes</option>
    <option>Capetown</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>Nice</option>
    <option>Geneva</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Based on the option selected i would like the div with id `#firmos` to change its value.

My current example changes the div text to a single value but i will need a different value for each option..

Any efficient ideas? The list of cities will be around 50.. maybe define an attribute within each `<option>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I looked that this plugin just replicates a `select` element in a `list <li>` and seems not possible to get the exact changed value from the `select` because it doesn't change if you see the `DOM` (that makes me assume that the `onchange` event from that plugin is used just to `trigger` something when your `list` changes).

So, it seems you need to do some tricky thing to get the `selected` value implementing an `onchange` event recreation.

Like this:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/nuRKE/

```
$(function () {

    var firmos = $('#firmos');

    $('#list4').jqDropDown({
        direction: 'up',
        defaultStyle: false,
        containerName: 'theContainer',
        toggleBtnName: 'awesomeToggleClass',
        optionListName: 'thisListIsRocking',
        effect: 'fade',
        effectSpeed: 300
    });

    //This will be your new 'onchange' event when using 'jqDropDown' plugin.
    $('ul .ddOption').on('click', function(e){
        var selected = $.trim($(e.target).text());
        switch (selected)
        {
          case 'Aspen':
            firmos.html('You selected Aspen.');
            break;
          case 'Tokyo':
            firmos.html('You selected Tokyo.');
            break;
          //Do the same for other options.
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: this works great - any chance to have a nice effect on the `firmos.html('You selected Aspen.');` change?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai you mean adding some effect like `fadeIn()` or something related? you can use those basic 'effects' but if you want something more elaborated, you can use `.animate(..)` method.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai I think you can try this: `firmos.html('You selected Aspen.').hide().fadeIn(3000);` or this one: `firmos.html('You selected Tokyo.').hide().slideDown(3000);` take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/nuRKE/1/ and `click` on 'Aspen' or 'Tokyo'.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may work.

```
jQuery("#firmos").html($(this).val());
```

In your document ready function it would look like this.

```
jQuery(function() {  
  jQuery('#list4').jqDropDown({ 
    optionChanged: function(){
      jQuery("#firmos").html($(this).val());
    }, 
    direction: 'up', 
    defaultStyle: false, 
    containerName: 'theContainer', 
    toggleBtnName: 'awesomeToggleClass', 
    optionListName: 'thisListIsRocking', 
    effect: 'fade', 
    effectSpeed: 300 
  });
});
```

**Edited**

Actually if you want to redisplay the option in another element this control has a parameter called place holder

you could do this.

```
jQuery(function() {  
  jQuery('#list4').jqDropDown({ 
    placeholder: '#firmos',
    direction: 'up', 
    defaultStyle: false, 
    containerName: 'theContainer', 
    toggleBtnName: 'awesomeToggleClass', 
    optionListName: 'thisListIsRocking', 
    effect: 'fade', 
    effectSpeed: 300 
  });
});
```

**Edited Again**

If you want a custom value you can do something like this

```
jQuery(function() {  
  jQuery('#list4').jqDropDown({ 
    optionChanged: function(){
      jQuery("#firmos").html((function (currentElement) {
        switch (currentElement.val())
        {
          case "someval":
            return "somethingSpecial1";
            break;
          case "someval2":
            return "somethingSpecial2";
            break;
          /// more case statements.
        }
      })($(this)));
    }, 
    direction: 'up', 
    defaultStyle: false, 
    containerName: 'theContainer', 
    toggleBtnName: 'awesomeToggleClass', 
    optionListName: 'thisListIsRocking', 
    effect: 'fade', 
    effectSpeed: 300 
  });
});
```

Comment: I dont want to display the actual text of the option but my own custom text for each option, hence define it as an attribute (?)

Comment: You can still use John's approach. Instead of directly using `$(this).val()` just make an object where the key is `$(this).val()` and the value is whatever custom text you want. Side note, `this.value` will also work.